# How to use jQuery parse this JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JS function like this

```
$.post(url, params, getFoodJSONText, "json");
```

and the call back function like this:

```
function getFoodJSONText(data) { parse JSON}
```

The return JSON like this:

```
{"result":[{"foodid":"3","price":"42","restaurantid":"1","picture_url":"/canteen/picture/food/3.jpg","foodname":"????"},{"foodid":"4","price":"38","restaurantid":"1","picture_url":"/canteen/picture/food/4.jpg","foodname":"?????"},{"foodid":"5","price":"48","restaurantid":"1","picture_url":"/canteen/picture/food/5.jpg","foodname":"?????"},{"foodid":"6","price":"42","restaurantid":"2","picture_url":"/canteen/picture/food/6.jpg","foodname":"???"}]}
```

I try to use

`$.each(data, function(i,item){
         alert(item.foodname[i]); 
         });`

but it won't works.

I have been searching this for quite a while but didn't get a good solution.

Anyone can suggest a way?

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

`item` will be the current array value, and `i` the current index.

Just use `item`. You will also want to iterate over `data.result` too, not just `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Call `each` with `data.result`:

```
$.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
    alert(this.foodname);
});
```

The iterator function will be called in the context of each member of the result array, so `this` will be equal to `item` within the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getFoodJSONText(data) {
    var food = $.parseJSON(data);

    //use food, for example:
    alert(food.result[0].foodid);
}
```

Comment: If the datatype is parsed as JSON, it should automatically decode it right?

Comment: Uhh, yeah, you are correct.  Sorry, I hadn't thoroughly read the question.  In this case the `var food = $.parseJSON(data)` declaration is totally unnecessary. But thanks anyway for the upvote.